Getting pages with highest drop-off from begin_checkout to purchase
I would like to know the pages that have the highest drop-off between the GA4 events "begin_checkout" and "purchase".
I tried custom path exploration as well as the Events and Purchase journey reports. For the path exploration, I didn't manage to get the breakdown by page name. And in the events report, the page name field was "not set" for the begin_checkout and purchase events. Whereas in the Purchase journey report, page name isn't available in the first place.
